# How can I upload linked OBJ and MTL files to BIM 360?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to use the Forge Api to upload linked OBJ and MTL files to a BIM 360 folder. I have been able to successfully upload the files separately, however I can't find how to "link" these files together.

Using the BIM 360 Document Management page, I am able to accomplish this by clicking the "Upload linked files" button, selecting my two files, and setting the OBJ file as the parent file.

How can I accomplish this using the Forge Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve the similar UI behavior "Upload linked files" by the Forge API, and I believe this blog post should be the one you are looking for..

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files